# How to map and copy multiple audio streams from one mkv to another using ffmpeg

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

So I have 2 files of the same video. One of the video files has two different audio streams

```
Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: flac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16 (default)
Stream #0:2(jpn): Audio: flac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16
```

I'm looking to map both of those streams and "paste" them on to the other identical file.

[Just so it could look something like this when you would open in mpc-hc or something.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PY66R.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to keep the existing audio in the uni-track video, then use

```
ffmpeg -i uni.mkv -i dual.mkv -c copy -map 0 -map -0:a -map 1:a swapped.mkv
```

(Remove `-map -0:a` if you do want to keep it)